# Access a collection of static Sublayouts from code behind in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore

In **Sitecore** how can I access all statically bound sublayouts from the code behind of an ASCX or and ASPX without knowing the ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach(var c in this.Controls){
  if(c is Sublayout) {
    var sl = (Sublayout)c;
  }
}
```

Or with LINQ:

```
var sublayouts = this.Controls.Where(c => (c is Sublayout)).Select(c = > (Sublayout)c);
```

**UPDATE:**

I was trying to do this recently by getting the `HtmlHead` control, so [I wrote a blog post on how to do it](http://firebreaksice.com/programmatically-add-controls-to-the-html-head-in-sitecore/). I just realized you can do something similar for sublayouts.

Here's a utility method to get controls on the page by their type:

```
WebUtil.FindControlsOfType(typeof(Sublayout), Sitecore.Context.Page.Page)
```

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned I tried that but the Controls collection doesn't contain any sitecore controls, just the other .NET controls.

Comment: Can you provide an example list of the control your page does find? I've done this before and was able to get the `Sublayout` so I'm really curious. Also, do you have HTML caching on for your outer control?

Comment: Sure, I get 3 Literal Controls, an HTMLHead, and an HTMLForm. Some background, I have a layout (aspx) that contains Sitecore FieldRenderers, Sublayouts, and a Placeholder. None can be seen from the Controls collection (from PageLoad) but I can access them by their ids. There is no cache explicitly set. Even more strange, the placeholder I mentioned has a sublayout (ascx) dynamically bound to it in the layout details within the cms. It also has statically bound sublayouts and a placeholder within it but i can see all sitecore controls from its Controls collection. I must be missing something.

Comment: Ahh, ok. I updated my answer with a way to do it using the Sitecore `WebUtil`

Comment: Mark, the WebUtil's FindControlsOfType method worked. Thanks. I still don't understand why they are not accessible in the Controls collection but they are from within an ASCX verses the ASPX.

Comment: Glad it worked. I think the reason is because the APSX is the outermost component, then there are controls within that, with controls within those, and so on. I think the WebUtil code **recursively** goes through all the controls to find what you need.

Comment: Just another similar followup: Within another ASCX control I have a FieldRenderer in the markup `<sc:FieldRenderer ID="MyField" />` In the code behind file, Visual Studio does not recognize the ID of the control i.e. `MyField.DataSource = [some source];` and gives an error on build but if I run the code in a web page it executes. Also, if I use the WebUtil method you mentioned previously I can find it that way.

Comment: The 2nd problem was the classic missing the designer file problem. Solved.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I misunderstand your question. But aren't you interested in getting the a certain items sublayouts and XSLT's?

In that case you have to access the Items LayoutDefinition as I mention in this blogpost: http://sitecorejm.blogspot.com/2007/09/getting-items-rendering.html

Is that what you want?

Comment: I don't think he wants rendering references, but rather references to each statically bound `Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Sublayout` as a control via C#.

Comment: No, just the statically bound sublayouts nested within my aspx. Within my aspx I have a defined control `<sc:Sublayout Path="[path_to_control]" ID="MySublayout" runat="server" />`. I want to dynamically access that control from the aspx's Page_Load method. The problem is when I iterate through the Controls collection that sitecore control isnt there.